# How to change a variable's value from knowing the local language of the phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, multilingual

I'm going to make things clearer. I have an android app which supports English and French.

From that, the app knows the used language on the phone and changes it's language if necessary. But in my app, I parse information from a URL, and I would like to change the value of this url compared to the language of the app (or phone).

**For french:**

```
String QUERY_URL = "https://api.immotoolbox.com/xml/2.0/MCRE/produits/?search[typeTransaction]=Vente&_locale=fr";
```

**For english :**

```
String QUERY_URL = "https://api.immotoolbox.com/xml/2.0/MCRE/produits/?search[typeTransaction]=Vente&_locale=en";
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define string named `query` for example in your `/values/strings.xml` and `/values-fr/strings.xml` resources:

```
/values/strings.xml:
<string name="query">your query in english</string>

/values-fr/strings.xml:
<string name="query">your query in french</string>
```

in your app just use the following to get your string:

```
String query = getActivity().getString(R.string.query);
```

If you using this in non activity or non fragment class do this :

pass any context to your class like that , with a constructor :

```
public YourClassName(Context context)
 { 
   this.context=context; 
 }
```

then : `context.getResources().getString(R.string.query_url);`

Comment: It doesn't know getActivity, and when I only put String query = getString(R.string.query_url); I have this --> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Jay are you calling this from a background task?

Comment: pass context to your class like that , with a constructor : public YourClassName(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

then context.getResources().getString(R.string.query_url);

Comment: @Jay it was getActivity() actually

Comment: @Pooya yes, I wrote getActivity() in my code, juste forgot the () in the comment, still not working, and no not in background, directly in an activity,in onCreate method

Comment: @Pooya my bad, I put this out of the onCreate String query_url = getString(R.string.query_url); I just put in onCreate, and it works, sorry for that ! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` which gives you the language code, then you can append it to your query.

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
if(!lang.equals("fr") && !lang.equals("en"))
    lang = "en";
builder.appendQueryParameter("local", lang);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
URL url = new URL(url+"?"+query);
```

Comment: I didn't try your solution, but it seems to be working as well, thanks @Ramin !